# Weird behavior in angular 2 subscribe when assigning data

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to angular js 2 and i am trying to use the subscribe but I found some weird behavior.. when im using the object searchresult on the html it has some data but using data internally on the ts file.. im having some problems of undefined

COMPONENT that is subscribed to the service

private searchResults: SearchResult;

```
  constructor(public searchEngineSvc: SearchEngineService) {
// this.searchResults = this.searchEngineSvc.retrieveData();
this.searchEngineSvc.pushedSearchResult.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.searchResults = data;
    console.log(this.searchResults);
    console.log(this.searchResults.stats);
  },
  error =>  {console.log(error);}
);
  }

ngOnInit() {
 this.searchResults = this.searchEngineSvc.retrieveData();
}
```

SERVICE

```
retrieveData() {
this.searchResult = {};
this.searchResult = new SearchResult(new Stats(), [], []);
console.log(this.searchResult);
this.subscription = this.retrieveDataHttpCall().subscribe(
  searchResult => {
    this.searchResult.data = searchResult.data;
    this.searchResult.stats = searchResult.stats;
    var ctr: number = 0;
    for (var key in searchResult.aggregations) {
      if (searchResult.aggregations.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.searchResult.aggregations.push(new Aggregation(key, false, []));
        for (var innerkley in searchResult.aggregations[key]) {
          if (searchResult.aggregations[key].hasOwnProperty(innerkley)) {
            this.searchResult.aggregations[ctr].aggregationObject.push(new AggregationObjects(innerkley, searchResult.aggregations[key][innerkley], true));
          }
        }
        ctr++;
      }
    };
  }
);
console.log(this.searchResult);
this.pushedSearchResult.emit(this.searchResult);
return this.searchResult;
}
```

this line from component will show some undefined values

```
console.log(this.searchResults.stats);
```

but this one shows it has some data

```
console.log(this.searchResults);
```

MODEL

```
import { Stats } from './stats'
import { Data } from './data'
import { Aggregation } from './aggregation'

export class SearchResult {
    constructor(
        public stats?:Stats, 
        public data?:Data[],
        public aggregations?:Aggregation[]){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it... put

```
this.pushedSearchResult.emit(this.searchResult);
```

inside

```
searchResult => {}
```

the reason for this is i think there is a race condition.. so puting it inside (searchResult => {}) will make sure there is a data to it before it broadcast

```
retrieveData() {
this.searchResult = {};
this.searchResult = new SearchResult(new Stats(), [], []);
this.subscription = this.retrieveDataHttpCall().subscribe(
  searchResult => {
    this.searchResult.data = searchResult.data;
    this.searchResult.stats = searchResult.stats;
    console.log(this.searchResult.stats);
    var ctr: number = 0;
    for (var key in searchResult.aggregations) {
      if (searchResult.aggregations.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.searchResult.aggregations.push(new Aggregation(key, false, []));
        for (var innerkley in searchResult.aggregations[key]) {
          if (searchResult.aggregations[key].hasOwnProperty(innerkley)) {
            this.searchResult.aggregations[ctr].aggregationObject.push(new AggregationObjects(innerkley, searchResult.aggregations[key][innerkley], true));
              }
            }
            ctr++;
          }
        };
        console.log(this.searchResult);
        this.pushedSearchResult.emit(this.searchResult);
      }
    );
    return this.searchResult;
}
```